# How to append XML Data node to existing file using Perl?

Tags: xml, perl

I have the list of directories in the following format

```
/temp/partner1
/temp/partner2
..
..
/temp/partnern
```

In each of the partner directories, a XML file will be available with unique name(Analytics.xml).

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<root>
    <GeneralParameters>   
        <PreviousX>250</PreviousX>    
        <PreviousY>37</PreviousY>    
        <NextX>169</NextX>
        <NextY>37</NextY>
        <CancelX>88</CancelX>
        <CancelY>37</CancelY>    
        <Height>399</Height>    
        <Width>513</Width>    
        <bgColor>EFEBDF</bgColor>    
        <GetServer>http://pipoffers.apnpartners.com/PIP/Server.jhtml?partner_id={partnerid}&amp;language={locale}</GetServer>       
        </Parameters>    
    </GeneralParameters>    

</root>
```

I want to parse the xml file in all the partner directories and append the `GetServer` node to the following value using perl script

```
http://pipoffers.apnpartners.com/PIP/Server.jhtml?partner_id={partnerid}&amp;language={locale}&amp;version={version}
```

Please suggest some ideas to proceed

Comment: You really need to show us more. What have you done so far for example? Right now this reads more as "do my homework" than a question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a moment to read [faq#ask] and revise your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stub to get you started:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# Iterate over directories
for my $dir (grep {-d} </temp/partner*>) {
    my $file = $dir . '/Analytics.xml'.

    if (!-e $file) {
        warn "File not found: $file\n";
        next;
    }

    # Use XML::Twig or XML::LibXML to process the xml
    # ...
}
```